# /blog (subdomain) 404 errors in webmaster tools /default.htm

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am new to Stackoverflow but a friend gave me a tip to ask my question over here since he couldn't help me as well. I have google's for multiple days now and I see that my rankings are dropping again in google because of all the crawl errors. My main site is build in serif webplus X5. I have added a wordpress blog to it which can be found at www.sitename .com/blog

Google has found more than 150 crawling errors and this is growing on a daily base, the point is that google ads behind all my blog url's /default.htm

I was wondering if someone can write me a htaccess 301 code for all these url's so it will instant redirect?

Today I started with manually redirecting some url's but this will not solve my problem because everytime I add another post and new tags all these new page's will also have the same default issue.

As you can imagine this is really frustrating grrr...

I have tried a lot of code's that I had found during my search but none of them did what I would like to achieve, other tips to get rid of the default page's are also very welcome.

Thank all of you who would like to fix this problem with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` rule in main WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /default\.htm [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)default\.htm$ /blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, 

There is still a problem because it needs to go to the sub domain /blog.

So what happens is you go to site .com/blog/bla/default.htm

and you will be redirected to 
site .com/bla (which is not excisting) 

can you add this to the code? I mean that it will redirect to the /blog/bla.

Thank you very very very much!

Comment: Yes YES!!! Oh I am so happy that this issue is fixed now you are awesome! And this is very usefull if someone else has the same issue because the solution is only here I googled my ass off. But Thanks again you are the best!

Comment: You're welcome, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.